# Browser link in Visual Studio 2015 - not functioning / no disable?

Tags: visual-studio-2015, browser-link

So from what I can tell Browserlink from 2013 has been moved up into 2015.  However, there seem to be two issues that I can't find the solution to with it.

First, it seems that my browserlink is failing to make a connection.  At first I noticed the errors in my firebug output shown below.  Then I double checked and the "quick update" that you are supposed to be getting via SignalR, definitely isn't happening.

[image: Browserlink in fire]

Second, I really can't find where the option to disable the browserlink is located.  If I can get it to work, I wouldn't mind trying it out.  However, if it isn't going to work, I'd much rather just disable it and not worry about it for now.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.  Note: I'm using Visual Studio 2015 Professional

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I was experiencing an even stranger issue. For a view that renders a very large amount of data browserlink caused `StackOverflowException` in System.Runtime.Serialization.dll. I have managed to disable it by adding the following in my web.config as stated [here](http://www.asp.net/visual-studio/overview/2013/using-browser-link#disabling):

```
<appSettings>
  <add key="vs:EnableBrowserLink" value="false"/>
</appSettings>
```

After adding this setting browserlink was disabled for real and there was no more `StackOverflowException`. Here are the screenshots of what it looked like before disabling browserlink:

[image: Exception in VS]

[image: Network log]

I know this is only a half of the answer but it actually seems that browserlink does not work well yet in some scenarios and needs some fixing...

Comment: We have the exact same problem after migrating a VS2013 Project. It took me a day to figure out. After deactivating BrowserLink, everythings works again.

Comment: For us the StackOverflowException seems to be caused by the combination of BrowserLink and PageInspector, which can also be disabled in the web.config (add key="PageInspector:ServerCodeMappingSupport" value="Disabled")